# In this linear algebra example, why does it follow that $c-2d=0$ and $d=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I don't understand why it follows that $c-2d=0$ and $d=0$. Can someone please explain?

[image]

Comment: Because $t$ is the indeterminate of the polynomials, not a number, and two polynomials are equal iff their coefficients are equal.

Comment: Please don't deface your question. No one can tell what you are asking if you take out the image (it doesn't matter if it has been answered already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need that $\forall t$

$$c-2d+dt=0$$

this requires precisely that $c=2d$ and $d=0$ that is $c=d=0$ which shows that, by definition, $p_1(t)$ and $p_2(t)$ are lineraly independent.